# displaying a group of divs by clicking next and back buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 divs that contain copy.

I have a back and next button, to display each div.

```
<a href="" class="back-btn off">Back</a> | <a href="" class="next-btn">Next</a>

<div class="vote-result first">
  this is example copy
</div>

<div class="vote-result">
  this is some more copy
</div>

<div class="vote-result">
  some more copy
</div>

<div class="vote-result">
  this is the last div
</div>
```

// hide the divs, except the first one.

```
.vote-result { display: none; }
.vote-result.first { display: block; }
```

The first time the next button link is clicked, I want to remove the off class, to show it as clickable, I probably should disable the link initially too and re-enable it too.

```
$(".back-btn").removeClass("off");
```

Once I display the last div, I need to add the off class to the next-btn and disable it.

I thought about using a carousel js plugin to accomplish this, but it is overkill for now.

I know of a way to do this, but it would involve assigning subclasses to the links based on what next or back button was clicked, so it will know what div to show next, as well as removing or adding the off class to the links.

I am hoping to find a solution that allows me to add more div's to display without modifying the code. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would advocate for my answer over Ashish's, in that mine keeps track of the state of the page using JavaScript variables instead of the DOM structure. When you start writing more and more advanced JavaScript, the ability to isolate the interface's state (which element is active) from the interface's DOM structure (how the element is presented) is increasingly more important as the DOM structure is highly likely to change frequently (or needs to change at a much later at a time when you've forgotten how the DOM represents data). My answer still relies on the DOM, but is much more isolated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution for you. I have created [**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/47fvk/) for your requirement.

HTML code:

```
<a class="back-btn off">Back</a> | <a class="next-btn">Next</a>

<div class="vote-result first selectedDiv">
  this is example copy
</div>

<div class="vote-result">
  this is some more copy
</div>

<div class="vote-result">
  some more copy
</div>

<div class="vote-result last">
  this is the last div
</div>
```

JS/JQuery Code:

```
$(".back-btn").click(function(){debugger;
    var prevElement=$('.selectedDiv').prev();
    prevElement.show();
    $(".selectedDiv").hide();                         
    $(".selectedDiv").removeClass("selectedDiv");
    prevElement.addClass("selectedDiv");                            

   if($('.first').css('display')=="block"){
       $(".back-btn").addClass("off");
   }
   else{
    $(".next-btn").removeClass("off");  
   }
});

$(".next-btn").click(function(){debugger;
    var nextElement= $('.selectedDiv').next();
    nextElement.show();
    $(".selectedDiv").hide();                         
    $(".selectedDiv").removeClass("selectedDiv");
    nextElement.addClass("selectedDiv");
    if($('.last').css('display')=="block"){
      $(".next-btn").addClass("off");
   }
   else{
     $(".back-btn").removeClass("off");  
   }
});
```

CSS code:

```
.vote-result { display: none; }
.vote-result.first { display: block; }
.off{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your HTML file:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .vote-result { display: none; }
            .vote-result.first { display: block; }
            .off {
                color: Red;
            }
            a {
                color: blue;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="code.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="" class="back-btn off">Back</a> | <a href="" class="next-btn">Next</a>

        <div class="vote-result first">
          this is example copy
        </div>

        <div class="vote-result">
          this is some more copy
        </div>

        <div class="vote-result">
          some more copy
        </div>

        <div class="vote-result">
          this is the last div
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Your new "code.js" file in the same directory:**

```
/**
 * The zero-based index of the <div class="vote-result"> element that is currently being shown
 * @var {Number}
 */
var activeIndex = 0;

function getNumberOfItems() {
    return $('.vote-result').length;
}

function synchronizeInterface() {
    var numberOfItems = getNumberOfItems(),
        lastIndex = numberOfItems - 1;

    $('.vote-result').removeClass('first');
    $('.vote-result').each(function(index) {
        if (index == activeIndex) {
            $(this).addClass('first');
        }
    })

    $('.back-btn').toggleClass('off', activeIndex == 0);
    $('.next-btn').toggleClass('off', activeIndex == lastIndex);
}

$(function() {
    $('.back-btn,.next-btn').on('click', function() {
        // If the button clicked is not deactivated
        if (!$(this).hasClass('off')) {
            // Determine whether the "Next" button was clicked (otherwise "Back" was clicked)
            var clickedNext = $(this).hasClass('next-btn');

            // Move the active index in the appropriate direction while not allowing it to fall outside the boundaries of appropriate indices
            activeIndex = clickedNext
                ? Math.min(activeIndex + 1, getNumberOfItems() - 1)
                : activeIndex = Math.max(0, activeIndex - 1);

            // Make sure the interface now reflects the updated JavaScript variables
            synchronizeInterface();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Some notes: You had an unclosed double-quote for one of your class attributes in your provided HTML. Also, I added some additional styling -- you may want to rename the ".first" CSS class to ".active" instead.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at jquerys .next() function for navigating - [jQuery - Next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/). you can also check for the last item like this.

```
if($(this).is(':last-child'))
{
    $('.next-btn').removeClass('off');
}else{
    $('.next-btn').addClass('off');
}
```

check everytime a navigation button is clicked and do the same for the first button