# display slider prev & next button dynamically

Tags: jquery, button

I am using the iDangerous swiper to create a simple carousel. Now I want the prev- and next-button to be displayed dynamically. For example: if you start the slider only the next-button is displayed. If you click, the next and prev-button will be displayed, and so on...

This is what I've been trying so far:

```
        var pos = $(".swiper-wrapper").position();
        if (pos.left === 0){
            $(".arrow-right").css("display", "block");
            $(".arrow-left").css("display", "none");
        } else if (pos.right === 0) {
            $(".arrow-right").css("display", "none");
            $(".arrow-left").css("display", "block");
        } else if (pos.right > 0 && pos.left > 0) {
            $(".arrow-right").css("display", "block");
            $(".arrow-left").css("display", "block");
        }
```

I've also been trying to wrap it into a function and call this one onClick

```
    $('.arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      mySwiper.swipePrev()
      somefunction()
    })
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle

Comment: you can also refer one of my similiar answers here-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004638/displaying-a-group-of-divs-by-clicking-next-and-back-buttons/25005313#25005313

Comment: yeah, just quick and dirty.. http://jsfiddle.net/FNL78/

Comment: added my answer. Can you please verify if it solves your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Updates [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FNL78/1/)

added `startpoint`, `first` and `last` to html div elements.
and added JQuery below code:

```
 if(this.className=='nxt'){
          $('.prv').show();
          var startpoint=$('.startpoint');
          startpoint.removeClass('startpoint');
          startpoint.next().addClass('startpoint');
          var endpoint=$('.endpoint');
          endpoint.removeClass('endpoint');
          endpoint.next().addClass('endpoint');

          if($('.last').attr('class')==$('.endpoint').attr('class')){
                $('.nxt').hide();
          }
 }
 if(this.className=='prv'){
          $('.nxt').show();
          var startpoint=$('.startpoint');
          startpoint.removeClass('startpoint');
          startpoint.prev().addClass('startpoint');
          var endpoint=$('.endpoint');
          endpoint.removeClass('endpoint');
          endpoint.prev().addClass('endpoint');

          if($('.first').attr('class')==$('.startpoint').attr('class')){
                          $('.prv').hide();
          }
  }
```